# Text block width while wrapping floating image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got some problem with text width while it wrapping floating image. Here is good picture what describe the problem:

[image: What I got]

This guy post kinda poem, but formatting of his text was broken. His text should looks like this:

[image: What I expect]

I'm already know the source of this problem. It because text block starts **behind** picture, and while text wrap around picture text block **not** growing longer and text stay in same bounds like there is no image at all. Here is the example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/czqGk/3/ I also add solution in JavaScript what do width compensation for text block.

**I'm looking for solution without using JavaScript.** Set minimum size of user post, or set another static width is not acceptable. Width should be dynamic and depends from content. Any ideas? :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Defining the image within the longer text seems to fix the issue; here's a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/glee/JPySN/2/).

Comment: You, sir. You awesome! I should just move image into blockquote. Thanks a lot :)